# Detecting cropped features/objects in an image

Tags: machine-learning, python, computer-vision

I hope someone can point me in the right direction. (Cross posting from the main SO flow page)

I have some images and I'm trying to write something in Python to detect if the objects in the image have been abruptly cropped.

For example notice in the first image below how the leaf in the top left has been cropped out of the canvas, or in the second how the top of the flower is cutoff.

How can I identify/classify images that have this? I imagine I could train a CNN off a labeled dataset? Also wondering if there is something more off the shelf or simpler?

Assume all images are very similar to the ones posted below.

[image: cutoff]

[image: cutoff2]

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77207737/detecting-cutoff-broken-features-in-an-image-due-to-cropping

Comment: are the images going to be related to natures (and similar to the one you shared) or your actual test set is more generic??